# VB - DataGridView doesnt Refresh

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I'm doing my PPA (Proof of Professional Aptitude) and i need to finish it in a month.

My DataGridView Style doens't refresh.

Nor when I take a field and not even when I change the width of the column.

Here's the design code:

```
    Private Sub DataGridProductsDesign() 'Procedimento que contem o novo estilo da datagrid
        tabelaprodutos.DataMember = "Produtos" 'Nome da tabela associada no datagrid
        tabelaprodutos.ReadOnly = False 'Coloca o datagrid apenas para leitura
        Dim GridStyle As New DataGridTableStyle 'Cria um novo estilo do datagrid
        GridStyle.MappingName = "Produtos" 'Associa a relacao da tabela clientes com a da base de dados
        Dim referenciaCol As New DataGridTextBoxColumn 'define a variavel do tipo DataGridTextBoxColumn
        referenciaCol.MappingName = "Referencia" 'atribui um campo da tabela
        referenciaCol.HeaderText = "Referencia" 'atribui um nome à coluna
        referenciaCol.Width = 110 'define tamanho coluna
        GridStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(referenciaCol) 'adiciona coluna
        Dim descricaoCol As New DataGridTextBox
        descricaoCol.MappingName = "descricao"
        descricaoCol.HeaderText = "Descricao"
        descricaoCol.Width = 210
        GridStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(descricaoCol)
        Dim precoCol As New DataGridTextBoxColumn
        precoCol.MappingName = "preco"
        precoCol.HeaderText = "Preco"
        precoCol.Width = 110
        GridStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(precoCol)
        Dim quantidadeCol As New DataGridTextBoxColumn
        quantidadeCol.MappingName = "quantidade"
        quantidadeCol.HeaderText = "Qauntidade"
        quantidadeCol.Width = 110
        GridStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(quantidadeCol)
        Dim disponivelCol As New DataGridTextBoxColumn
        disponivelCol.MappingName = "disponivel"
        disponivelCol.HeaderText = "Disponivel"
        disponivelCol.Width = 110
        GridStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(disponivelCol)

    End Sub
```

Hope you guys can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: A DGV doesnt need to be 'refreshed' - they datasource does.  What are we supposed to glean from that wall of code?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: @Plutonix i'm sorry, tried to make it cleaner now.

so.. what do you mean? what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Yeah, adding the word "design" doesnt clarify anything.  You should know that the NET 1.1 DataGrid  is not the same as the DataGridView from NET 2.0+.  Please read [Ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: @Plutonix thank you for the help. have a great day